# How can I make "Force change password during first login attempt" after registering

Tags: struts

My action is:

```
public class LoginAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {

    /**
     * This is the action called from the Struts framework.
     * @param mapping The ActionMapping used to select this instance.
     * @param form The optional ActionForm bean for this request.
     * @param request The HTTP Request we are processing.
     * @param response The HTTP Response we are processing.
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm) form;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        String userName = loginForm.getUsername();
        System.out.print("name::" + userName);

       List list=new ArrayList();
        String passWord = loginForm.getPassword();
        System.out.print("here is Actionform::" + loginForm.toString());
         list = StudentloginDAO.studentLogin(userName, passWord);





        if (list.size() > 0) {
              int id = (Integer) list.get(0);

        System.out.println("id is" + id);
        System.out.println(" List :: " + list.size());
        System.out.println(" List :: " + list);
        List<StudentSessionObjectStore> list1 = StudentSessionObject.studentSessionObject(id);
        System.out.println("new list" + list1.size());
        System.out.println("new list value" + list1);
        session.setAttribute("getsessionObject", list1);
        System.out.println("the Action attribute" + session.getAttribute("getsessionObject"));
            return mapping.findForward(Constants.ACTION_FORWARD_SUCCESS);
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("LoginResult", Constants.ACTION_FORWARD_FAILURE);
            return mapping.findForward(Constants.ACTION_FORWARD_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is I want to go to changePassword.jsp for force password Change when user first time login.

Could anybody help me?????

Answer (score 1):

(FYI, the posted code is totally irrelevant to the question.)

Why are you storing the current user in a list? It's a single user.

In any case, you need to track if it's the user's first login in the DB. You could do that with a simple flag, or, more relevantly in the long run, by tracking how many times they've logged in.

If the "has logged in?" flag isn't set, or the number of logins is zero, redirect them to the "change password" page. At that point you'll need to make sure they've actually changed the password and disallow site movement until they've done so.